# Getting Error "TypeError: Failed to fetch" While running graphql endpoint in ChromeiQL

Tags: magento2.3, localhost, graphql

I am running xampp server in my windows local. I setup magento 2.3.2 with sample data in it.

When i try to run graphql in ChromeiQL , it throws error "TypeError: Failed to fetch". I have been using a default magento only. No customizations.

If i try to run graphql endpoint with a remove linux server, it works fine. The issue happens in local system only, not only in my pc, other local pcs as well.

I have attached here a ref. image for the error. Document explorer is also empty. Could any one help me what could be the issue here ?

Ref. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/pfx7gp

Comment: What is the query you tried with?

Comment: No any queries working. Actually Document Explorer itself is not being loaded.

Comment: did you try with magento default grapgQl query like getting cms Page?

Comment: It's not about default query or custom query, none of the queries could be executed because of this error.

Comment: How did you fixed that problem? I am also facing the same situation

Comment: @VaibhavMunjpara, I am having same issue. Can you please let us know how did you fix it ?